# How can I parse this text file in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, text

[Example Data Link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2363305/Programming/Parse/SampleData.txt) - Sorry, wouldn't format correctly when pasted.

```
1.
 Dec 01, 2011
 06:00:00 AM
 Dec 01, 2011
 07:05:00 AM
 65
2.11
2.
 Dec 01, 2011
 06:00:00 PM
 Dec 01, 2011
 07:05:00 PM
 65
2.11
3.
 Dec 02, 2011
 06:05:00 AM
 Dec 02, 2011
 07:05:00 AM
 60
1.95
```

I'd like each separate line to have its own place in an array or datatable, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. There must be something different with the ending characters?

Code is below:

```
Dim strOutput As String = ""

'' Demo Data
'Dim strData As String = "59. Dec 01, 2011 06:05:00 PM Dec 01, 2011 10:05:00 PM 240 80.00"
'strOutput = +FormatRow(strData)
'' Demo Data

Dim sFileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sFileName) Then
    Dim srFileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim sInputLine As String
    srFileReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(sFileName)
    sInputLine = srFileReader.ReadLine()

    Do Until sInputLine Is Nothing
        'strOutput = +FormatRow(sInputLine)
        Dim title As String = srFileReader.ReadLine()
        Dim startTime As DateTime = srFileReader.ReadLine() & " " & srFileReader.ReadLine()
        Dim endTime As DateTime = srFileReader.ReadLine() & " " & srFileReader.ReadLine()
        Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = endTime.Subtract(startTime)
        Dim minutesTotal As Integer = timeSpan.TotalMinutes
        ' Burn Minutes
        srFileReader.ReadLine()
        Dim billMinutes As Integer = minutesTotal
        Dim billTotal As Double = srFileReader.ReadLine()

        strOutput += ""
    Loop
```

Output something like:

```
12/1/2011 6:00:00 AM    12/1/2011 7:05:00 AM    65  65      2.11
```

Comment: Please format that data file content and add it to your post.

Comment: What do you mean format it? When I copy and paste it, stackoverflow changes the formatting. I'll try to paste some of it, it is just a plain text file.

Comment: what is the format of the output?

Comment: Why do you call ReadToEnd? Also, isn't your loop infinite?

Comment: @Landmine - Each record is scattered in 7 lines? Am I right?

Comment: @Landmine - Have a look at my post. Please be careful about array index while reading/traversing it. (Please check the bounds and handle  exceptions if any)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have read while text file at once and I think File.ReadAllLines will be good choice.

```
 Dim str
 Dim fileName = "C:\SampleData.txt"

 Dim lines() = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)

 For i = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0) Step 7
  str = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", 
                     lines(i), lines(i + 1), lines(i + 2), lines(i + 3), 
                     lines(i + 4), lines(i + 5))
  Console.WriteLine(str)
 Next
```

Comment: Updated the output format, think I could send you the files? Cause I'm getting a lot of rows of the same data.